# generating entity from cs file code in edmx

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I started a sample entity framework project. I've the EntityModel.edmx file, when I clicked the EntityModel.Designer.cs file, it opens a file written:

```
// T4 code generation is enabled for model 'c:\users\scala\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\entityFramework\entityFramework\EntityModel.edmx'. 
// To enable legacy code generation, change the value of the 'Code Generation Strategy' designer
// property to 'Legacy ObjectContext'. This property is available in the Properties Window when the model
// is open in the designer.

// If no context and entity classes have been generated, it may be because you created an empty model but
// have not yet chosen which version of Entity Framework to use. To generate a context class and entity
// classes for your model, open the model in the designer, right-click on the designer surface, and
// select 'Update Model from Database...', 'Generate Database from Model...', or 'Add Code Generation
// Item...'.
```

I cannot get the entity code. How can I get the entity code? I can not change the 'Code Generation Strategy' designer
property to 'Legacy ObjectContext' in the property window.

Comment: I suggest u to use code first rather then db first for full control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read carefully what is written in the comments:

> To generate a context class and entity classes for your model, open the model in the designer, right-click on the designer surface, and select 'Update Model from Database...', 'Generate Database from Model...', or 'Add Code Generation Item...'.

'Add Code Generation Item...' will do the trick. You should basically choose and add one or more T4 templates to actually generate the entities. More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj613116.aspx). Also take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30918926/1948038). It might help to make things clear.

Comment: Any time, also take a look at the link I've added to the answer recently - there is more detailed explanation there.