# The difference between EF6 and EF4.1 in files hierarchy

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-6, edmx

I'm a beginner to Entity Framework .

I notice that When I use `EF6 with Visual studio 2013`:

I have `.Designer.cs` empty file with this comment:

```
  // T4 code generation is enabled for model 'C:\Users\Luka\Desktop\Test\EF-db2008\AdventureWorks\AdventureWorksLib\AdventureWorksLib\AWLTModel.edmx'. 
    // To enable legacy code generation, change the value of the 'Code Generation Strategy' designer
    // property to 'Legacy ObjectContext'. This property is available in the Properties Window when the model
    // is open in the designer.

    // If no context and entity classes have been generated, it may be because you created an empty model but
    // have not yet chosen which version of Entity Framework to use. To generate a context class and entity
    // classes for your model, open the model in the designer, right-click on the designer surface, and
    // select 'Update Model from Database...', 'Generate Database from Model...', or 'Add Code Generation
    // Item...'.
```

`.Context.tt` and its `.Context.cs`
with code like this:

```
 public partial class AWLTEntities : DbContext
    {
        public AWLTEntities()
            : base("name=AWLTEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    }
```

And then `.tt` file with `.cs` file for each entity like `Customer.cs`

With code like this :

```
 public partial class Customer
    {
        public Customer()
        {
            this.NameStyle = false;
            this.CustomerAddresses = new HashSet<CustomerAddress>();
            this.Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
        }

        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    }
```

---

This 's totally different when i use `EF4.1 with visual studio 2010` ,
there's only one code behind file `.Designer.cs` for the model !!

---

- Could some one help me to understand what are all these files for 
  `.Context.tt` , `.Context.cs`,`.tt`,`.cs` ?and what 's different
  in files hierarchy between the two cases`(EF6,EF4.1)`?
- I can't find `OnPropertyChanging(Value) & OnPropertyChanged()` in
  `EF6` to validate my entities !!Why these methods no longer exist and how to validate my
  properties if they do not exist?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So lets make it clear step by step:

- You've got your `.edmx` file, which was created from designer or generated from existing database. But it's only an xml file, which contains info about the database structure that is used - [storage scheme](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj652016.aspx), info about entities -  [conceptual schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj652004.aspx) and mappings between those two. It doesn't contain any executable code. This code needs to be generated.
- To generate the code the `.edmx` file will be parsed and `.cs` files will be created that contain actual executable code. 2 approaches might be used:

  1. Generator build-in the Visual Studio - the [EntityModelCodeGenerator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/01/24/how-does-the-ado-net-entity-designer-generate-code.aspx) tool. That is a legacy approach, that was used previously (in Visaul Studio 2010 in your case). This will generate only the `.Designer.cs` file with all classes inside it. But this approach is not the best - you cannot modify generation process for your needs (say, add `DataMember` attribute to generated classes or some other changes). That's why it's better to use
  2. [T4 templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx). These are files with `.tt` extension. All they do is just execute their logic when `Run custom tool` is chosen in context menu, or `.edmx` file is changed. There is a set of available templates for generating EF code from `.edmx`, some info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj613116.aspx). And because these are just regular files, you could modify them as you need (to get better editor experience use [tangible T4 extension](http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/T4-Editor-Visual-T4-Editing.html)). Some basic info about the usage of T4 templates in EF [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg558520.aspx).

You can choose between these 2 approaches independently of Visual Studio version - just change the `Code generation strategy` property in the properties of your `.edmx` file:

[image]

If the `Legacy ObjectContext` option is chosen - you get 1-st way with single `.Designer.cs` file. If `T4` - then the `.Designer.cs` will be empty (with comments saying that T4 templates are used) and `.tt` files will generate the used code. So if you need the same code as in VS 2010 - just use `Legacy ObjectContext` option.

Another difference between those two is that 1-st generates legacy `ObjectContext` and entities that are derived from [EntityObect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.dataclasses.entityobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). They all will be in that `.Designer.cs` file. But that is not recommended any more (however you can still get [corresponding T4 template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj613116.aspx#EntityObject) - in that way you'll get your `OnPropertyChanged` and `OnPropertyChanging` back, because they are the methods of `EntityObect` class, however they are protected, so you might need to write some wrappers). But its better to use [POCO classes and DbContext template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj613116.aspx#DbContext) - the one that VS 2013 used in your case. Then you'll get separate `.Context.tt` to generate `.Context.cs` with derived `DbContext` in it with `DbSets` representing tables, and `.tt` file to generate the entity classes. And the hierarchy between `.tt` and `.cs` only shows which `.cs` were generated by which `.tt`, while only `.cs` will be actually complied and executed when your app runs.

- And now regarding `OnPropertyChanged` - that should be just an implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. However looks like you are using template that generate POCO classes. That is the default and recommended option, but to get the implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` you might need to edit the template or choose another one from Visual Studio Online gallery. That's, however, might not be the best architectural solution, because it is sometimes better to separate entities and the classes you use for UI/Business logic.

Comment: Also noteworthy, the EDMX is going away in EF7. So none of this will be applicable after EF 6.

Comment: Yes, but that is sore subject in EF7, worth a separate thread, not a comment) But in short - on our current project we cannot upgrade to EF 7 exactly because of that - we use existing database and "Update model from db" approach, which is [not well supported](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/10/21/ef7-what-does-code-first-only-really-mean.aspx). E.g., we have custom mapping names, and they would be reset if we would use reverse-engineer for Code First, and we cannot afford renaming in all our code - too massive refactoring. And function mappings are not supported in Code First.

Comment: And I suppose there would be no `after EF 6` because EF 7 is just [differs too much](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/10/27/ef7-v1-or-v7.aspx), so we might even have 2 frameworks for different needs - EF 6 and EF 7.

Comment: All agreed. I only spoke up because the question was asking about the edmx differences across versions.

Answer (score 3):

`*.tt` files are [T4 templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) used to autogenerate c# code from [`.EDMX` file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj650889.aspx). This is basically your storage scheme, conceptual scheme and a mapping between them. The `.context.cs` is your `DbContext` (former `ObjectContext`) and other are entities. The tool used to generate code is `EntityModelCodeGenerator` as seen in properties of `.edmx` file. So it is pretty straight forward.

In order to get `OnPropertyChanged` that was for `EntityObject` class you can try Self-Tracking Entities as per [this manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj613924). But as you see it is not advised now... Probably all it'd be required to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interfaces in your entities (they are `partial`). `EntityObject` was replaced by the proxy classes. EF generates them for each entity (can be turned off). And includes a tracking there. Hope it helps!

UPDATE. So you can use it to generate validation in entities themselves but that would be some logic or event handling. Usually this is placed into separate modules, into services to "free up" mind. Of course it depends on your specific case, requirements.

Comment: STE definitelly should not be used just to get OnPropertyChanged - a few custom lines in T4 template will do it. And with STE you've got the ChangeTracker and all that horrible stuff that might be helpful for N-tier apps (when you don't have access to context and have to track changes somehow), but it is implemented so.... messy that its now obsolete. [Other techics](https://ntieref.codeplex.com/) has been developed to implement support for N-tier EF, but, once more, that is much more difficult task than just implement INotifyPropertyChanged